# Meaning of connectionTimeout in tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

What does that parameter mean for tomcat. It was declared in `server.xml`  as follows:

```
 <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

So, I tried to change it

```
 <Connector connectionTimeout="2" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

and didn't notice any effect. I expected that each page the load takes for more than 2 milliseconds would produce 504 - connection timeout error. But it didn't. I'm using eclipse and modify that file through it.

Comment: Apparently the setting is used for multiple things: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45380028/32453

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Taken from here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

> `connectionTimeout`
>
> The number of milliseconds this Connector will wait, after accepting a
>   connection, for the request URI line to be presented. Use a value of
>   -1 to indicate no (i.e. infinite) timeout. The default value is 60000 (i.e. 60 seconds) but note that the standard server.xml that ships
>   with Tomcat sets this to 20000 (i.e. 20 seconds). Unless
>   disableUploadTimeout is set to false, this timeout will also be used
>   when reading the request body (if any).

Answer (score 21):

This parameter is there specifically to fight one type of Denial-Of-Service attack,
whereby some malicious client(s) **create a TCP connection to the server (which has the effect of reserving some resources on the server for handling this connection)**, and then **just sit there without sending any HTTP request on that connection**.
By making this delay shorter, you shorten the time during which the server resources are
allocated, to serve a request that will never come.