# SpringBoot: server.tomcat.connection-timeout NOT WORKING

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to Timeout the request if no response is received in 5s. I tried server.tomcat.connection-timeout, but No Luck.

I am aware of ***spring.mvc.async.request-timeout*** property using *Callable<?>*, but ***server.tomcat.connection-timeout*** should work ,right?

application.properties

```
server.tomcat.connection-timeout=5s
```

Rest Controller

```
@PostMapping("/getdata")
public String call() throws Exception {

    Thread.sleep(10000);

    return "Hello";

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.revise</groupId>
    <artifactId>database</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>database</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: How are you running your application (jar or deploying a war)? Which Spring Boot version are you using? Please provide additional information.

Comment: Try changing Callable<String> signature, if you use spring mvc, refer: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-timeout#spring-mvc-request-timeout

Comment: @M.Deinum I have added the pom.xml

Comment: @huy but even server.tomcat.connection-timeout should work right?

Comment: you should add the config for spring mvc also spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=5000 and try again...

Comment: The connection-timeout isn't what you think it is. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839941/meaning-of-connectiontimeout-in-tomcat/30840242 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643647/what-exactly-does-connectiontimeout-means-in-tomcat#:~:text=In%20the%20docs%20(Tomcat%207,no%20(i.e.%20infinite)%20timeout. In your case a proper request is send thus the timeout doesn't apply.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ok got it, Thanks... If get into any infinite loop, i just want to come out of it. Is there anyway to timeout other than making use of Callable<T> interface?

Comment: You won't come out either way. While the connection will timeout it doesn't kill the processing on the server, only the connection is closed. The server will continue the process anyway but cannot send the response.

Comment: @M.Deinum Oh...I am so confused ... So basically we cannot kill the process and return a response or Throw an error if I run into an infinite loop?... Sorry, I am new to all these, so trying to catch up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting in Spring MVC to control the timeout of request handled by Controller unless of-course you are using Async processing which basically means you need to return a `Callable<>` if you want `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout` to work. The property you are mentioning `server.tomcat.connection-timeout` is actually a tomcat property ( which is set up by Spring Boot) which basically refers to timeout if the client opens a connection but is not sending or it's very slow to send the request ( uri, headers etc. as per http protocol)

> The number of milliseconds this Connector will wait, after accepting a
> connection, for the request URI line to be presented. Use a value of
> -1 to indicate no (i.e. infinite) timeout.

You can check [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21914) for an issue reported in Spring Boot and the comments by Spring team.